# Rating system - Five star problem

Tags: 8, entities, rating

I tried to use 2 modules, [FiveStar](https://www.drupal.org/project/fivestar) and [Rate](https://www.drupal.org/project/rate) to put rating system on a new custom content I created but neither worked.

When I try to put FiveStar in a field of my content it shows me this error:
[image]

I don't know why but if I don't put any star on default rating it won't work..
So I have to put my products since they are created all by default with some rank (from 1 to 5 stars or 10 if I change the number or stars they can have)for this to work and that's kind of bad..

I wanted my products to come with no evaluation/rating when they are created.

EDIT:

Now with the rate module I manage to do this, but I now how I change from thumps up/down to stars (from the module or a costumized ones) ?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using the [Votingapi Widgets](https://www.drupal.org/project/votingapi_widgets) module based on the [Voting API](https://www.drupal.org/project/votingapi) in D8, it works and does the same as [Fivestar](https://www.drupal.org/project/fivestar).

Some more details about this module (from its project page):

> A flexible field based Voting System based on [Voting API](https://www.drupal.org/project/votingapi).
>
> You need Drupal Version >= 8.2.3. (Multiple form instances on a page).

**Be aware**: only an alfa3 release for D8 as of right now.

Comment: The module seems good but I can't display the stars in my content for others, only when creating. Can you give me some tutorial on how to work properly with this module?

Comment: Have you properly set the field display in your view mode?

Comment: That was my problem, I only had Drupal 8.2.2

Comment: Ok great, glad that works now for you!